# How to calculate regional discount for some product in PHP?

Tags: php, math, discount

So I was asking ChatGPT about the regional discount. First about places where to get "cost of living" and "average salary". I've created a small JSON file with data from Numbeo. And now I need to calculate a regional discount, I have something that cost $100 (Paid support for my Open Source project to be exact), but I want to offer a smaller price for countries with lower income (like Poland where I live).

I want to do that in PHP, how should I calculate the discount for Poland?

Here is a row in the JSON table for Poland. I'm not sure if I need other data to create a discount.

```
{"country":"Poland","cost of living":38.6,"salary":1033.68}
```

The cost of living is compared to New York which has 100 (this is at least what ChatGPT was telling me). The average salary in the USA is 4,208.18. I would use proportion for this, but I have way too many variables.

If my thinking about the discount based on that two variables is not correct, I also would like to know this.

Answer (score 1):

I think a better approach is to use the [Purchasing Power Parity (PPP) - GDP](https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/PA.NUS.PPPC.RF) index, which takes into account the cost of living in different countries and adjusts for the relative value of money in each country.

> Purchasing Power Parity (PPP) can be used as a factor to reduce or increase the price of a product in a certain country. PPP is a concept used to calculate the differences in purchasing power between two or more countries. This concept takes into account the differences in prices of the same goods and services in different countries and calculates the average price of those goods and services across all countries. Thus, PPP provides a more accurate way to calculate the purchasing power of people in different countries.

To adjust the price for Poland, you can divide the PPP index by 1 (which represents the index for the US), and multiply the result by 100. In this case, the price adjustment factor would be:

```
0.573 / 1 * 100 = 57.3
```

This means that prices in Poland are about 57% lower than in the US when adjusted for the cost of living.

Discount :

```
$100 * 57.3 / 100 = $57.30
```

Let's play :

```php
$price = 100; // original price in USD
$pppIndex = 0.573; // PPP index for Poland in 2020
$priceAdjustmentFactor = $pppIndex / 1 * 100; // calculate price adjustment factor
$discountedPrice = $price * $priceAdjustmentFactor / 100; // calculate discounted price

echo "Discounted price for Poland: " . $discountedPrice . " USD";
```

Comment: Thanks, will check the calculation when having time since I need to find that PPP index and generate the files.